# Combo box populates a text field - JavaScript and user input

Tags: javascript, encoding, combobox, populate

### Setup

What I need in the end: a combo box and a text field. Selecting an item from the combo box populates a value in the text field. Items in the combo box come from user input.

This is my current code that works nice:

```
function fill() {
  var select = document.getElementById("select");
  var value = select.options[select.selectedIndex].value;
  var textfield = document.getElementById("textfield");
  switch (value) {
  case "1":
    textfield.value = "some user-provided text";
    break;
  case "2":
    textfield.value = "containing possibly < > & etc.";
    break;
  }
}

<select id="select" onchange="fill()">
  <option>Select something...</option>
  <option value="1">Select option 1</option>
  <option value="2">Select option 2</option>
</select>

<input type="text" id="textfield"/>
```

### Problem

I am not sure what to do if the user-provided text to populate contains dangerous characters. Usually I would HTML-encode it before writing it in the HTML code, but now I am writing it into JavaScript code.

All of the JavaScript is generated by a Java backend. I can't really create it like this:

```
String value = getValueFromUser();
write("textfield.value = \"" + value + "\";");
```

Because then someone would enter `"; somethingBad(); //` and some other user would on selecting this option get `somethingBad()` executed.

If I HTML-encode the value:

```
String value = htmlEncode(getValueFromUser());
write("textfield.value = \"" + value + "\";");
```

Then (security questions aside) after selecting a value in the combo box the text field will be populated with HTML-encoded text.

### Question

How do I encode the user-provided values so that:

- They cannot be misused for JavaScript code injection, and
- They look the same after being populated into the text field?

Comment: If your server-side code needs to include user-entered data within what will become a JS string, rather than `htmlEncode()` you can do a string replace to change any `"` character to `\"`. If the user-entered data might include carriage returns or line feeds you should replace them too. Then what the browser sees will just be a valid JS string.

Comment: So how would you describe this transformation? Getting the user input to be a valid JS string?...

Comment: Would it be overkill to just send JSON-encoded plain text and JSON-encoded html entities altogether? This would move all encoding to the server, thus avoiding any potential security issues. 
Home-grown encoding schemes can and usually will fail. Keep it simple...

Comment: I don't want to use any non-standard encoding, that is why I am trying to avoid most of the answers here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me throw in my own idea.

My Java code generates hidden HTML elements (e.g. spans) containing HTML-encoded input from the user:

```
<span id="case1" class="hidden">some user-provided text</span>
<span id="case2" class="hidden">containing possibly &gt; &lt; &amp; etc.</span>
```

Then my JavaScript code will use the value from here:

```
function fill() {
  var select = document.getElementById("select");
  var value = select.options[select.selectedIndex].value;
  var textfield = document.getElementById("textfield");
  switch (value) {
  case "1":
    textfield.value = document.getElementById("case1").innerHTML;
    break;
  case "2":
    textfield.value = document.getElementById("case2").innerHTML;
    break;
  }
}
```

This way I don't need to worry about encoding the user input to be safe inside JavaScript code - it's never inside JS code! It's just inside HTML, and it's well known how to HTML-encode so that it's safe.

The obvious drawback is generating hidden HTML elements, but it seems like an acceptable compromise...

Comment: change document.getElementById(xxx).value to document.getElementById(xxx).innerHTML and it will work

Answer (score 1):

Store your values escaped, then:

```
String value = getEscapedValueFromUser();
write("textfield.value = unescape(\"" + value + "\");");
```

This will get rid of brackets, quotes and '=' from your stored string preventing any malicious code.

EDIT after comments below:

Your best bet really would be to escape() it in js when you validate the input and store it fully escaped. Then you just have to add unescape() to the write() line outside your "..." as in the code above.

This encodes most special chars [just google 'js escape()' for references] and you definately won't be able to get out of the "...", no going on to the next line if there are line breaks, no chars that need to be included in malicious code, string always ends up as input because escape/unescape are complementary, you won't forget anything and won't accidentally encode a genuine '\n' as [enter] in the destination string.

If you don't want to do this as you may have collected a lot of unescaped values in your database already, or use them elsewhere and can't change the db to hold an extra field, you should replicate the escape function in java as far as you think you need it [after further thought to be safe you should encode all control characters and `"'()%=;`, or just replicate the whole function, wouldn't be too hard].

Comment: What does the `escape()` here do? Is it the HTML-escape? In that case, is there a JavaScript function `unescape()`?

Comment: escape() % encodes most of the special characters which will make the string safe to write(), and as in the code block above it can be unescape()ed.

Comment: `escape()` needs to be a Java method. Which exact escaping strategy you recommend? (that is the crux of this SO question)

Comment: How are you getting value from user? All you would need to do with the string is either escape it before it gets to java or replace ()'%" and = with their % encoded values in java. Unescape works with a string that contains unescaped characters too.

Comment: The value from the user comes from a regular HTML form. In the meantime it's stored in the database, but that's not important for the moment.
Can you please point me to an authoritative answer to the question "Why is escaping ()'%" enough"? Are you sure escaping in this way is enough?

Comment: You are dynamically generating the js for your page. Your goal is to stop somethingbad() from running. Your value is going into a quoted literal string in js. The only way to inject code here is to come out of your " ... ". To do this here, any malicious input must contain the " character, so you need to encode it either in java or before (e.g. with %22). If there is a genuine use of %xx in the user input you want it to stay, so you also need to encode the % symbol (e.g. with %25). The () and = encoding is belt and braces as 1 of these would be required in malicious code.

Comment: Also encoding ' would mean you can quote inside this symbol in the js if you want later.

Comment: I see your point about escaping the `" ... "`. However, I am still skeptical about just encoding `"` to something else, because I do not know what other character sequences get translated to `"` or interpreted as such. For this reason I would prefer to find a tried solution, preferably with some "references".

Comment: I can't comment on your answer yet as not enough points :(. Seems like your approach could work, but you would need to test that the value coming back is the same as the entered value (same spacing/breaking particularly). The advantage of escape/unescape is that they are designed to be complementary - you are not relying on a passive conversion that may be platform dependant. Also if you are multi-developer, there is a danger that someone else could use the value without the same care as you. Better to have them display junk than run unsafe code...

Comment: Of course all the user-provided code will be encode()d before being included in the HTML code of the page, always. So the multi-developer concern seems not that relevant. I don't see the point about checking the value coming back - This whole thing is used as a populate feature only - whatever the user types in the textfield is OK for me.

Comment: I meant that I am not 100% confident that the `span.value` will return exactly as spaced in the user input value (multiple white space may be truncated to one space in some browsers). I would be 100% confident that `unescape()` will return exactly what was `escape('input')`d in js, and that the `escape('input')`d value will not contain the " or break characters (therefore safe here). If you are confident about the `span.value`, or it doesn't matter too much then I guess you have 2 ways to skin a cat. I can't see either method being difficult to implement or causing a bottleneck...

Comment: I don't mind if `span.value` changes whitespaces or truncates them. Anyway, thanks for the help :) Let me wait if some guru gives yet another answer, but the bounty seems to be yours.

Comment: Any chance of receiving that bounty then?!

Answer (score 0):

I generally use the following function that will return a string to display any text as typed:

```
function RemoveEntities (TextToReplace) 
{
    var ReplacedText='';
    var CurrentChar='';
    if (typeof TextToReplace=='number') {TextToReplace=TextToReplace.toString();}
    for (i=0;i<TextToReplace.length;i++)

    {
        CurrentChar=TextToReplace.substring(i,i+1);
        if (CurrentChar=="&") {ReplacedText=ReplacedText+"&amp;";} 
        else if (CurrentChar=="<") {ReplacedText=ReplacedText+"&lt;";} 
        else if (CurrentChar==">") {ReplacedText=ReplacedText+"&gt;";} 
        else if (CurrentChar==" ") {ReplacedText=ReplacedText+"&nbsp;";} 
        else if (CurrentChar=="'") {ReplacedText=ReplacedText+"&apos;";} 
        else if (CurrentChar=='"') {ReplacedText=ReplacedText+"&quot;";} 
        else if (escape(CurrentChar)=='%0A' || escape(CurrentChar)=='%0C') {ReplacedText=ReplacedText+"<br/>";}
        else {ReplacedText=ReplacedText+CurrentChar;}
    }
return ReplacedText;
}
```

This should work fine for short text inputs. Could also be shortened with += or global replace statements but I haven't had to optimise this yet (not been a bottleneck).

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but is this not just an (incomplete) HTML encoding?

Comment: Apologies, should read the question before answering - this will not display as typed in a text field. The risk of code injection depends on what you are doing with the string down the line. You can escape() your value to store it and unescape() when you need it for display / use.

Comment: I need to encode the string so that I can use it in generated JS, that will in turn fill it out in a HTML form.

Comment: I see the problem now, could you escape() the value to store it and then call a function when it is loaded to unescape() the values in your combo box?

Comment: This is mixing two things. HTML-escaping a string does not mean it's safe to put it inside JS code.

Comment: I am yet to see any dangerous code that doesn't contain brackets to call a function, which are parsed out when escaping. This will be OK when setting the values dynamically with write(). You can then iterate through the combo box values, reseting value with unescape(value).